# Is the boundary of a bounded set bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(M,d)$ be a metric space and let $S$ be a bounded subset of $M$. I'd like to know if we can say anything about $\partial S$, the boundary of $S$. By definition, $p\in M$ is a boundary point of $S$ if every open ball centered at $p$ intersects not only $S$ but also $M\setminus S$. In my opinion, that suggests $\partial S$ is tantalizingly close to $S$, thus justifying its name. Now I would like to hazard a guess: **$\partial S$ is bounded**.

Since $S$ is bounded, we can choose an open ball $B(x,r)$ to enclose $S$. Then our intuition about boundaries implies that $\partial S\subseteq B(x,r)$. To prove it, we must choose an arbitrary point $p\in\partial S$ and show that $p\in B(x,r)$. We begin by letting $r_p=\min\{d(p,x),r-d(p,x)\}$. Then $B(p,r_p)\subseteq B(x,r)$; indeed, for each $y\in B(p,r_p)$,
$$d(y,x)\leq d(y,p)+d(p,x)<r_p+d(p,x)<r.$$
Is my reasoning above legitimate enough to ensure boundedness of $\partial S$? Thank you.

**Update(2022.8.3):** There seem to be some logical flaws in my original proof that $\partial S$ is bounded, so I coined another proof, which is based heavily on knowledge of closures of sets. Now, according to our previous discussion, $S\subseteq B(x,r)$. Taking the closures, we see
$$\overline{S}\subseteq\overline{B(x,r)}.$$
Surely, $\overline{B(x,r)}$ is the closed ball with center $x$ and radius $r$, and by enlarging it a little bit, we can see $\overline{S}$ contained in some other open ball. Now, $\overline{S}$ is bounded (consistent with the comment by @Mason), and then
$$\partial S=\overline{S}\cap\overline{M\setminus S}$$
tells us that $\partial S$ is bounded, too.

Comment: Even $\overline{S}$ is bounded. This follows from $diam(S) = diam(\overline{S})$, which can be shown fairly easily.